# WebStorm set iterator value on debug JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm for debugging my nodejs code. I've got a simple for loop on 100 times .

```
for (var i = 0; i<100 ; i++) { console.log(i); }
```

How can I set value for the `i` variable in the debugger?

When I press <kbd>F2</kbd> and change the value to any number I get an error of "Cannot convert undefined or null to object".

Comment: have you ever heard about Dictionary?

Comment: Yes, but how can I implement that in the debugger?